# Weird json decoder behaviour

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode, swifty-json

So, I have userInfo data that I got from notification and I want to decode and pass this data to another class. I use swiftyJSON for json decoder. This is my code:

```
func decodedNotificationTransactionData(data: Any, completionHandler: @escaping (_ dict: [String : Any]) -> ()){

    let dict = JSON(data)

    print ("this is json data \(dict)")
    print("this is status \(dict["status"])")

    let test = [
        "id" : "\(dict["id"])",
        "orderDate" : "\(dict["orderDate"])",
        "patientName" : "\(dict["patient"]["fullName"])",
        "patientAddress" : "\(dict["patient"]["address"])",
        "caregiverName" : "\(dict["care"]["fullName"])",
        "caregiverAddress" : "\(dict["care"]["address"])",
        "serviceType" : "\(dict["service"]["label"])",
        "status" : "\(dict["status"])",
        "price" : "\(dict["totalAmount"])",
        "otherNote" : "\(dict["otherNote"])",
        "totalService" : dict["detailDatas"].count,
        "serviceLongType" : dict["detailDatas"][0]["type"],
        "jsonContent" : dict
        ] as [String : Any]

    completionHandler(test)

}
```

[this the "print ("this is json data (dict)")" result](http://pasted.co/7cafdd85)

[json data](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbddb836)

When the code reach **print ("this is json data (dict)")** the data is there with no problem but when the code reach **print("this is status (dict["status"])")** it gives null on the log. Have you ever experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look in the SwiftyJSON documentation reveals the error immediately:

> Creates a JSON object.
>      - parameter object: the object.
>      **- note: this does not parse a `String` into JSON, instead use `init(parseJSON: String)`**.
>      - returns: the created JSON object
>
> ```
> public init(_ object: Any) {
> ```

So you have to use

```
let dict = JSON(parseJSON: data)
```

Comment: It works for me. But I do have a question, why is this happening? I use "JSON(res)" on my API Call and it doesn't have any problem.

Comment: But I do have to convert my "data" to string with "data as! String" to use your solution. Btw, I get the "data" from "func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)".

Comment: To make it clear: If the `data` parameter in `decodedNotificationTransactionData(data...` is `Data` use `JSON(data)`, however in your example it's obviously `String` so you have to use `JSON(parseJSON: data)`

Comment: Ok, now I understand what causes the issue. Thanks a lot for the help and explanation.